# Как задать сортировку (CompareTo) с учетом всех элементов коллекции?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть класс такого вида

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? Field1 { get; set; }
    public int? Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Коллекция выглядит примерно так

```
1 1

2 N

3 N

4 5

5 N

N 2

N 3

N 4

N 6
```

И должна после сортировки выглядеть так

```
1 1

2 N

3 N

N 2

N 3

N 4

4 5

5 N

N 6
```

При этом "N 2" < "3 N", но должен идти после, потому что элементы должны идти группой по первому элементу. Просто если бы я указал, что "N 2" > "3 N", то N 2 было бы больше и 5 N... а оно меньше. Короче не знаю, насколько понятно я объяснил. Задавайте вопросы наводящие.

Comment: вообще непонятно что хочется :) и при чем тут `CompareTo`? и как сортировать? и правила сортировки совсем не очевидны, как мне кажется

Comment: @Grundy, если в двух словах - это карта изменения строк в файле, в отличие от оригинального. 2 N означает, что строка 2 в исходном файле была удалена. N 2 означает что строка 2 была добавлена во 2й файл. Вместе они означают, что вторая строка исходного файла была изменена во втором файле... как то так...

Comment: @Grundy в результате по этой карте я буду выстраивать изменения. При этом удаленные подряд строки должны будут отображаться над добавленными (чтобы не было зебры удалено/добавлено/удалено/добавлено)

Comment: Чтобы выполнить алгоритмическую сортировку, нужно задать строгое правило сравнения любых двух элементов набора. Пока вы этого не сделаете, вам здесь не помогут. А если вы сможете сформулировать такое правило, то думаю что и сами справитесь.

Comment: @iksuy, гениально

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass: IComparable
{
  public int? Field1 { get; set; }
  public int? Field2 { get; set; }
  public int CompareTo(object obj)
  {
    return Функция_описывающая_правило_больше_меньше(this, obj as MyClass);
  }
}
```

P.S.
Возможно это вам поможет?

```
//Внимание! Алгоритм работает в том случае, если хотя бы один field в каждом из экземпляров класса задан. 
//Просто иного варианта Вы не описывали
int Функция_описывающая_правило_больше_меньше(MyClass a,MyClass b)
{
  int a1 = a.Field1.HasValue ? a.Field1.Value : a.Field2.Value; 
  int a2 = a.Field2.HasValue ? a.Field2.Value : a.Field1.Value; 
  int b1 = b.Field1.HasValue ? b.Field1.Value : b.Field2.Value; 
  int b2 = b.Field2.HasValue ? b.Field2.Value : b.Field1.Value; 
  int minCompare = Math.Min(a1,a2).CompareTo(Math.Min(b1,b2));
  if (minCompare == 0)
    return Math.Max(a1,a2).CompareTo(Math.Max(b1,b2));
  return minCompare;
}
```

Comment: собственно весь вопрос в определении этой `Функция_описывающая_правило_больше_меньше` и был :)

Comment: Тогда надо бы описать поподробнее это правило. Из текста выше понятно только то, что это сферический конь в вакууме.

Comment: И такой комментарий уже есть под вопросом :)

Comment: Ну я не нашёл очевидного. iRumba пишет, что хотелось бы организовать сортировку. Возможно он имел ввиду от какого интерфейса наследоваться для алгоритмов сортировки, допустим, `System.Linq`. А вот текста вроде "как мне написать правило сортировки моих элементов" я у него не нашёл. Возможно я неправильно понял неправильно поставленный вопрос... Тогда примите мои извинения.. =)

Comment: Тема называется `Как задать сортировку (CompareTo) с учетом всех элементов коллекции?` не зря. Для того, чтобы из приведенной мною в примере коллекции получить отсортированную нужным образом колекцию, нужно при сравнении двух элементов учесть остальные

Comment: Ну в PS я написал вариант алгоритма. Попробуйте, устроит?

Comment: Обратите внимание, `N 2` > `3 N`, но при этом меньше '5 N'... Ваш компаратор это не учтет...

Comment: Можете объяснить почему так? Я сломал мозг понимая Ваши требования. =)

Comment: Если вы хотите сортировать в зависимости от других элементов, то можно создать класс, реализующий `IComparer`, передать в конструктор этого класса саму коллекцию. Тогда метод `Compare` сможет обращаться к любому элементу коллекции.

Comment: Я в вопросе предложил 2 коллекции. Исходную и отсортированную. В комментариях для Grundy я объяснил для чего все это

Comment: @iksuy, а вот это хорошая идея

Comment: Я наверное слишком туп, всё равно не понял с Ваших комментариев порядок сортировки.

Comment: Это карта изменений, которые некто внес в некоторый файл. Разбор построчный. Field1 - строка в оригинальном файле. Field2 - строка во втором файле. Если строка была удалена, то экземпляр будет таким, например - `2 N` (вторая строка была удалена). Если строка была добавлена, то экземпляр карты будет `N 3`, например (на третью строку была добавлена строка)

Comment: Дак а где правило сортировки то??? я не пойму почему 5N > N 2 > 3 N

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, типа того, но при определенных условиях все может поменяться. :) Строки иду по порядку. Причем и строки первого файла и строки второго. но в случаях, когда строки были добавлены или удалены (когда одно из полей == null), эти строки тоже надо куда то деть. Логично, что элемент с Field1 == 2 должен идти после элемента с Field1 == 1. Но и элемент с Field2 == 2 должен идти после Field2 == 1. но тогда как разрулить два элемента 2 N и N 2? Для этого просто нужно решить какой из них меньше. Я решил, что меньшим будет 2 N.....

Comment: ... Но когда есть несколько элементов с одним отсутствующим полем, а вторым имеющим перечисление i++, компаратор с такой логикой выстроит их так: 2 N, N 2, 3 N, N 3, 4 N, N 4 и тд.... но я хочу чтобы в этом случае они располагались так 2 N, 3 N, 4 N, N 2, N 3, N 4. Я не знаю как еще подробнее это объяснить... :(